# How to calculate the odds of winning 5+1 prize?

Tags: combinatorics

I was practicing some combinatorics, when I stumbled upon this problem:

In a lottery game with numbers 1-39 you have to pick 7 and 1 additional one. What are the odds of winning a prize by getting 5 of those 7 correct plus that additional one (a 5+1 prize)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The odds of getting a given number correct are clearly 1/39, and the odds of getting one wrong are 38/39. So, the odds of getting five correct and two wrong, in a particular order, are $\left(\frac{1}{39}\right)^5 \left(\frac{38}{39}\right)^2$. The total odds of getting five correct and two wrong will be the above times the number of possible orders, which is ${5 \choose 2} = \frac{5!}{2!3!} = 10$. The requirement to get the one extra number right adds an additional factor of $1/39$, so the total probability is $10\left(\frac{1}{39}\right)^6 \left(\frac{38}{39}\right)^2$.